# Event Store linkTo not creating stream

Tags: eventstoredb

I am running a projection against my events using 'linkTo' to create a separate stream as advised by Rob Ashton (http://codeofrob.com/entries/re-partitioning-streams-in-the-event-store-for-better-projections.html) but it's not working.

I've even tried creating a project that runs across all events in all streams, but still no stream is created using linkTo as shown in the image below:

[image]

What changes need to be made for 'linkTo' to actually create a stream? I'm using EventStore 2.0.1 for .NET running on Windows 8. I can see the following in the Event Store console:

```
[03284,13,11:16:44.614] Enabling 'Test' projection
[03284,13,11:16:44.663] 'Test' projection source has been written
[03284,14,11:16:44.663] Creating an event distribution point at 'C:0/P:-1'
[03284,14,11:16:44.663] The 'de018cce-02dc-41fa-b0ee-09422fa69ce6' projection subscribed to the 'e0bf8ffc-64a2-4882-8051
-646f4f0e8c39' distribution point
[03284,14,11:16:44.705] The 'de018cce-02dc-41fa-b0ee-09422fa69ce6' subscription has unsubscribed (reader: e0bf8ffc-64a2-
4882-8051-646f4f0e8c39)
```

Answer (score 0):

Projections are not enabled by default. You will need to start eventstore with the following command line parameter:

--run-projections=all

[EventStore Command Line Arguments](https://github.com/eventstore/eventstore/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments)